# Does Force-Directed Layout of d3-js support image as node?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, force-layout

[d3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) has [a demo of a Force-Directed Graph Layout](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html).

Instead of circles, I want all nodes in the graph to be images.

so, I changed

```
 .append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);
```

to

```
.append("xhtml:img")
   .attr("src", "http://a577.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/081/Purple/12/61/13/mzi.lgqdzwfu.png")
   .call(force.drag);
```

But I can not see any images. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
node.append("svg:image")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://d3nwyuy0nl342s.cloudfront.net/images/icons/public.png")
    .attr("x", "-8px")
    .attr("y", "-8px")
    .attr("width", "16px")
    .attr("height", "16px");
```

Here is an example of using an image as the node: http://bl.ocks.org/950642

Comment: Do you happen to know how to make the rect image as a circle image inside a circle node? Your given example will show a circle and a rect image inside it. Thanks.

Comment: @derek, how about   border-radius: 100%; css style?

Comment: border-radius doesn't work on svg:image but there is hope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430580/setting-rounded-corners-for-svgimage