# Setting rounded corners on an image using Highcharts Renderer

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I am using the Highcharts js library and rendering my users' avatars on the canvas using the Highcharts Renderer methods. I need the avatars to be rendered with rounded corners rather than square, unfortunately I am obtaining the avatars through Gravatar, so it is not possible to modify the images beforehand.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430580/setting-rounded-corners-for-svgimage), except that I haven't been able to figure out how to implement it using the Highcharts API.

```
var xpos = chart.chartWidth/2;
var ypos = chart.plotTop + chart.plotSizeY/2;
chart.renderer.image('http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2ce72b95b9ed68d79a99d717b58ec64c?s=70', xpos-35, ypos-35, 70, 70).add();
```

Comment: See the similar topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430580/setting-rounded-corners-for-svgimage

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that. I swear I spent ages looking before I posted a question. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [Sebastian Bochan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2021935/sebastian-bochan):

> See the similar topic
>   [Setting rounded corners for svg:image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430580/setting-rounded-corners-for-svgimage)