# Need to append square image to circular node d3.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

Hi Im trying to add square images to circular nodes but cropping the image to the node size. Ive successfully added the images but cant seem to crop them to the circular node. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

```
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(json.nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag)
      .on('mouseover', connectedNodes)
      .on('mouseout', allNodes)
      .on('contextmenu', function(d){d3.event.preventDefault();tip.show(d);})  //.on('mousedown', tip.show)
    .on('mouseleave', tip.hide);

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.degree;})
    .style("fill", function (d) {return color(d.group);})
    node.append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href",  function(d) { return d.image;})
        .attr("x", function(d) { return -25;})
        .attr("y", function(d) { return -25;})
        .attr("height", 50)
        .attr("width", 50);
```

I also want to show the node there if there isn't any image.

Comment: You need to use a pattern, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202450/adding-an-image-within-a-circle-object-in-d3-javascript) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881186/d3-fill-shape-with-image-using-pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use svg clip paths.

**Code Sample:**

```js
var nodes = [{
  "id": "0",
  "name": "ETCO I",
  "degree": 50,
  x: 100,
  y: 150

}, {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "PINKERTON Eidel ",  
  "degree": 25,
  x: 200,
  y: 100
}];

var container = d3.select("svg");

var node = container.append("g").selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });

node.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id",function(d,i){ return "node_clip"+i })
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r",function(d) {
    return d.degree-2; //-2 to see a small border line
  });


node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.degree;
  })
  .style("fill", "blue");

node.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
    return "https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/group-of-people-in-a-formation_318-44341.png";
  })
  .attr("x",function(d){ return -d.degree })
  .attr("y",function(d){ return -d.degree })
  .attr("height", function(d){ return d.degree*2 })
  .attr("width", function(d){ return d.degree*2 })
  .attr("clip-path",function(d,i){ return "url(#node_clip"+i+")" });
```

```css
svg {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width=500 height=200></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first answer here will help you setting a circle as the mask for an image: [Setting rounded corners for svg:image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430580/setting-rounded-corners-for-svgimage).
Other than that, if using SVG is not really a requirement for you, you could implement the graphics using normal HTML and CSS3, and use good old `border-radius: 50%` on `<img>` tags, or their containers for that matter.

Comment: Unfortunatly that didnt work for me as I'm loading the images from an array using     node.append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href",  function(d) { return d.image;})