# How to make a images border-radius in draw2d-js?

Tags: css, svg, draw2d-js

I have this question in `draw2d-js`,
there is a user images and want to make it looks like `css3  border-radius`.

I have used `draw2d.shape.basic.Image`, but it did not work in style `css border-radius`.

Do any one knows how to make it?

Thanks very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the accepted answer here, I think you will find that it also answers your question...
[Setting rounded corners for svg:image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430580/setting-rounded-corners-for-svgimage)

For reference I am including the content of the above answer here as well.

> 'border-radius' doesn't apply to svg:image elements (yet anyway). A
>   workaround would be to create a rect with rounded corners, and use a
>   clip-path.
>
> An example:
>   http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/clippath/border-radius-on-image.svg
>
> The relevant part of the source:

```
<defs>
    <rect id="rect" x="25%" y="25%" width="50%" height="50%" rx="15"/>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <use xlink:href="#rect"/>
    </clipPath>
</defs>
<use xlink:href="#rect" stroke-width="2" stroke="black"/>
<image xlink:href="boston.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
```

> It's also possible to create several rect elements instead of using