# Is HighCharts custom marker symbol shape modifiable?

Tags: highcharts

In the Documents `symbol` can pass `url()` for displaying custom image symbol, but if my image is square and I need it to display as rounded shape, is HighCharts supporting this or I need custom css to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highcharts only gives the possibility to set custom marker symbol using `url()`, but under the hood that symbol occurs as an `SVGImageElement`, so basically it is not able to apply the for example `border-radius` parameter on it.
The simplest way to achieve the effect you need is by editing the image.
Also you can dynamically add the `<rect>` element for every symbol and set it as a `clipRect` of a specific image.

Best regards!

Comment: can you provide a working sample for using `<rect>`? much appreciated.

Comment: hi @TravisSu, sorry for late. Here is the topic, which should be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430580/setting-rounded-corners-for-svgimage . There you can find the example and description how to implement it.

Comment: I copy pasted the answer code and plug-in with my own image url but it doesn't show up anything....

Comment: This example shows how to use `clipPath` parameter combined with SVG image, so It's not general solution for all issues. You need to refactor the code and adjust it to your expectations.